# Rust struct with primitive types only stil moved?

Tags: rust, struct

So, I came across this code in the Rust Book (Brown University version):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let rect1 = Rectangle {
        width: 30,
        height: 50,
    };
    let a = area(rect1);
    println!("{} * {} = {}", rect1.width, rect1.height, a);
}

fn area(rectangle: Rectangle) -> u32 {
    rectangle.width * rectangle.height
}
```

This code does not compile because when we called the `area(rect1)` we moved the `Rectangle`. But the `Rectangle` contains field of `u32` type which is a primitive type and thus implements `Copy` trait. Then this should be allowed to compile. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6):

`Copy` is not an auto trait (fun fact: it used to be, pre-1.0). The fact that all of your fields implement it doesn't mean you implement it too. You need to implement it (or derive it) explicitly:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value `rect1` gets moved to `area` when you called it. Then it gets dropped at the end of the `area` fn, unless you return it back (and bind it).

There's a number of ways to fix this. Two that come to mind:

- you can change `area` to take a borrow `&`
- you can derive `Clone` on your struct and send `area(rect1.clone())`.